# Uploading File into Server and store the path in database in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very new to ROR. I have a task to finish:

Here's the Model:

```
class File::DataImport < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :created_by, :file_name, :file_source, :updated_at, :updated_by
end
```

Here's the Controller:

```
class Files::DataImportsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def new
  end
end
```

And the views I have are `index` and `new`.

I want a field to upload data. The data should be stored in the server and save the filepath into the database in a specified column `file_name`. The path should be default to all uploading files.

I am stuck with how to start. Please help me to find the solution and I will learn from this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

db/migrate/20110711000004_create_files.rb

```
class CreateFiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
  create_table :files do |t|
  t.string :name
  # If using MySQL, blobs default to 64k, so we have to give
  # an explicit size to extend them
  t.binary :data, :limit => 1.megabyte
  end
end
end
```

app/controllers/upload_controller.rb

```
 class UploadController < ApplicationController
 def get
 @file = File.new
 end
 end
```

app/views/upload/get.html.erb

```
<% form_for(:file,
url: {action: 'save'},
html: {multipart: true}) do |form| %>
Upload your file: <%= form.file_field("uploaded_file") %><br/>
<%= submit_tag("Upload file") %>
<% end %>
```

app/models/file.rb

```
class File < ActiveRecord::Base
def uploaded_file=(file_field)
self.name = base_part_of(file_field.original_filename)
self.data = file_field.read
end
def base_part_of(file_name)
File.basename(file_name).gsub(/[^\w._-]/, '')
end
end
```

app/controllers/upload_controller.rb

```
def save
@file = File.new(params[:file])
if @file.save
redirect_to(action: 'show', id: @file.id)
else
render(action: :get)
end
end
```

app/controllers/upload_controller.rb

```
def file
@file = File.find(params[:id])
send_data(@File.data,
filename: @File.name,
disposition: "inline")
end
```

app/controllers/upload_controller.rb

```
def show
@file = File.find(params[:id])
end
```

app/views/upload/show.html.erb

```
<h3><%= @file.name %></h3>
<img src="<%= url_for(:action => 'file', :id => @file.id) %>"/>
```

Comment: I have tried your solution 9year later and I have this error: Unpermitted parameter: :uploaded_file if you are still alive could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

you should consider using one of the already available solutions like paperclip: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip or carrierwave: https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave

Besides the Readmes there are also good tutorials out there:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip

http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads

edit: As you want to implement it yourself I recommend examining the sources of the above on Github and try to understand what their code is doing. Also I would not bother implementing it myself, but if you have your reasons this might get you going..

Comment: Hello frank, Thanks for your reply. But I should not use any gem or plugins for this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into a solution such as [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave).

The Github page provides a good explanation on how to use it, but [this](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2011/a-gentle-introduction-to-carrierwave/) is also a nice guide.

Comment: Hi Zajn, Thanks and the problem is that i should not use any gem or any plugin's.

Comment: What is restricting you from using a gem? It's probably better to not try and reinvent the wheel here, unless you have a really good reason to do so.

Comment: This is like a Test. So I should learn from this.... That's why i should not use any gem or any plugin's.