# save csv and xml in mysql column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Project model which has several attachments, attachments are xml and csvs. Rather than uploading these attachments to server, I just want to save them in table ( I do however want users to upload these attachments). Each project can have multiple attachments, then I am going to parse these attachments.

Any ideas how to do this ?

Comment: So? What problem do you have? Lets user upload file, save it in db and delete it from filesystem then.

Comment: I don't know how to do it :)

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12484333/uploading-file-into-server-and-store-the-path-in-database-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0):

I hope below railscast episodes will help you.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel